# Breeze API Controller - The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze, single-page-application, hottowel

I am getting this error when attempting to call the

```
public object Lookups() {

  var divisions = _contextProvider.Context.Divisions;                      

  return divisions;
}
```

on the Breeze API controller.

The ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type

What I'm I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Return an object, not an IQueryable.

```
public object Lookups() {

  var divisions = _contextProvider.Context.Divisions;                      

  return new { divisions };
}
```

Comment: Problem still persists... I've also tried removing all virtual collections from the Division POCO class - nothing as well...